# Riemann Curvature: How to proof the identical relation and why ${R_{1212}}$ is only independent variant about Riemann Curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This question comes from analysis the differential geometry.

What proof thought is? I don't know it.

The 1st question: how to proof the 4 identical relations.

The 2nd question: why ${R_{1212}}$ is only independent variant?

$$
\begin{align}
R_{mijk} = \sum_\ell g_{m\ell} R_{ijk}^\ell , \quad m,i,j,k = 1,2.\\[6pt]
\begin{cases}
R_{mijk} =  - R_{imjk},\\
R_{mijk} =  - R_{mikj},\\
R_{mijk} = R_{jkmi}, \\
R_{mijk} + R_{mjki} + R_{mkij} = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: 1st and 2nd identity shows that m and i are different and k and j are different.This leaves only two possibilities 1212 and 2121 which are are upto a minus sign.

Comment: For 2nd question, I don't know why only 1212 is independent variant. And For 1st question, the 4 identical relations , how to proof them?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422304) and plug $n=2$ into $n^2(n^2-1)/12$ which gives the number of independent components.

Answer (score 0):

I only give some steps, but I didn't proof them. Because of difficulty.

Steps1:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
{R_{mijk}} = \sum\limits_l {{g_{ml}}R_{ijk}^l}  = {g_{m1}}R_{ijk}^1 + {g_{m2}}R_{ijk}^2 = {g_{m1}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ij}^1}}{{\partial {u^k}}} - \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ik}^1}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \sum\limits_p {\left( {\Gamma _{ij}^p\Gamma _{pk}^1 - \Gamma _{ik}^p\Gamma _{pj}^1} \right)} } \right)\\
 + {g_{m2}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ij}^2}}{{\partial {u^k}}} - \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ik}^2}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \sum\limits_p {\left( {\Gamma _{ij}^p\Gamma _{pk}^2 - \Gamma _{ik}^p\Gamma _{pj}^2} \right)} } \right)\\
{R_{imjk}} = \sum\limits_l {{g_{il}}R_{mjk}^l}  = {g_{i1}}R_{mjk}^1 + {g_{i2}}R_{mjk}^2 = {g_{i1}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \Gamma _{mj}^1}}{{\partial {u^k}}} - \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{mk}^1}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \sum\limits_p {\left( {\Gamma _{mj}^p\Gamma _{pk}^1 - \Gamma _{mk}^p\Gamma _{pj}^1} \right)} } \right)\\
 + {g_{i2}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \Gamma _{mj}^2}}{{\partial {u^k}}} - \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{mk}^2}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \sum\limits_p {\left( {\Gamma _{mj}^p\Gamma _{pk}^2 - \Gamma _{mk}^p\Gamma _{pj}^2} \right)} } \right)
\end{array}
$$

Steps2:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum\limits_p {\left( {{g_{i1}}\Gamma _{mj}^p\Gamma _{pk}^1 - {g_{i1}}\Gamma _{mk}^p\Gamma _{pj}^1} \right)} \\
\sum\limits_p {\left( {{g_{m1}}\Gamma _{ij}^p\Gamma _{pk}^1 - {g_{m1}}\Gamma _{ik}^p\Gamma _{pj}^1} \right)} \\
{g_{i1}}\Gamma _{mj}^p = ? - {g_{m1}}\Gamma _{ij}^p\\
\Gamma _{mj}^p = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} [mj,l] = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {r_{mj}} \cdot {r_l}\\
\Gamma _{ij}^p = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} [ij,l] = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {r_{ij}} \cdot {r_l}\\
{g_{i1}}\Gamma _{mj}^p = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {g_{i1}} \cdot {r_{mj}} \cdot {r_l} = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {r_i} \cdot {r_1} \cdot {r_{mj}} \cdot {r_l}\\
{g_{m1}}\Gamma _{ij}^p = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {g_{m1}} \cdot {r_{ij}} \cdot {r_l} = \sum\limits_l {{g^{pl}}} {r_m} \cdot {r_1} \cdot {r_{ij}} \cdot {r_l}\\
{r_i} \cdot {r_{mj}} = ? - {r_m} \cdot {r_{ij}}
\end{array}
$$

Steps3:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
{r_i} \cdot {r_{mj}} = ? - {r_m} \cdot {r_{ij}}\\
{r_{mj}} \cdot {r_i} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\partial {g_{mi}}}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \frac{{\partial {g_{ji}}}}{{\partial {u^m}}} - \frac{{\partial {g_{mj}}}}{{\partial {u^i}}}} \right)\\
{r_{ij}} \cdot {r_m} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\partial {g_{im}}}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \frac{{\partial {g_{jm}}}}{{\partial {u^i}}} - \frac{{\partial {g_{ij}}}}{{\partial {u^m}}}} \right)\\
{r_i} \cdot {r_{mj}} \ne  - {r_m} \cdot {r_{ij}}???
\end{array}
$$

PS: The definition you need is here:

$$
\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{r_{ij}} \cdot {r_l} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\partial {g_{il}}}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \frac{{\partial {g_{jl}}}}{{\partial {u^i}}} - \frac{{\partial {g_{ij}}}}{{\partial {u^l}}}} \right) = [ij,l] = \sum\limits_k {\Gamma _{ij}^k{g_{kl}}} ,k = 1,2.}\\
{\Gamma _{ij}^k = \sum\limits_l {{g^{kl}}} [ij,l]\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}
\end{array}}
\end{array}} \right.
$$

$$
R_{ijk}^l = \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ij}^l}}{{\partial {u^k}}} - \frac{{\partial \Gamma _{ik}^l}}{{\partial {u^j}}} + \sum\limits_p {\left( {\Gamma _{ij}^p\Gamma _{pk}^l - \Gamma _{ik}^p\Gamma _{pj}^l} \right)} ,i,j,k,l,p = 1,2.
$$

Anyone can help me?